# sublimetext3 find and replace with regex shows weird behaviour: is it my fault or bug?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm doing little replace job: I want to remove some double quotes that should not be there for correct syntax, in image below.

[image: strings I want to replace]

therefore I built a regex that captures such a pattern into double-quoteless one, namely

[image: regex]

however, when I run "replace all",

[image: strings replaced]

double quotes are removed as expected, but upper- and lower-case are affected weirdly, as you can see. What am I doing wrong? Is this expected result?

Comment: I can't repro on Build 3126.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found it myself - if Preserve case(Alt+A in windows) is turned on, it will show such a behaviour. Turning off that solved the problem.

[image: correct result]

[image: correct setting]